# Creating JSON DataContract class VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, dictionary, nested-lists, datacontract

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON String into a class, however I'm having difficulty constructing the DataContract Class.

Here's an example of the JSON Response String:

```
{
    "id": null, 
    "result": {
                    "SCD2": {
                                "connected": false
                            }, 
                    "FHM1": {
                                "connected": false
                            }, 
                    "SCD1": {
                                "connected": false
                            }, 
                    "POS2": {
                                "connected": false
                            }, 
                    "POS1": {
                                "connected": false
                            }
            }, 
    "error": null
}
```

Here is the class that I have so far.. I can't figure out what to do for the results datamember:

```
<DataContract()> _
Public Class JSON_RESP
    'region Properties

    <DataMember(Name:="id")> Public id As String

    <DataMember(Name:="result")> Public result As New List(Of String)

    <DataMember(Name:="error")> Public errors As New JSON_ERROR

    'endregion

End Class

<DataContract()> _
Public Class JSON_ERROR
    'region Properties

    <DataMember(Name:="fault")> Public fault As String

    <DataMember(Name:="faultCode")> Public faultCode As String

    <DataMember(Name:="faultString")> Public faultString As String

    'endregion
End Class
```

Comment: I made some changes to make it more generic, however I'm hoping for a more elegant way to accomplish this:

Comment: thats an odd looking JSON. see how it breaks down: http://jsonutils.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes that appear to work and make this more generic, however I would like a more elegant solutions:

_
Public Class JSON_RESP(Of T)
    'region Properties

```
<DataMember(Name:="id")> Public id As String

<DataMember(Name:="result")> Public result As T

<DataMember(Name:="error")> Public errors As New JSON_ERROR

'endregion
```

End Class

_
Public Class SwitchStatus
    'region Properties

```
<DataMember(Name:="POS1")> Public POS1 As New ConnectionStatus
<DataMember(Name:="POS2")> Public POS2 As New ConnectionStatus
<DataMember(Name:="SCD1")> Public SCD1 As New ConnectionStatus
<DataMember(Name:="SCD2")> Public SCD2 As New ConnectionStatus
<DataMember(Name:="FHM1")> Public SCD3 As New ConnectionStatus

'endregion
```

End Class

_
Public Class ConnectionStatus
    'region Properties

```
<DataMember(Name:="connected")> Public connected As Boolean

'endregion
```

End Class

Comment: you dont need `New` on the declarations just to deserialize